# I have a problem when I run on the web Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized databaseFactory

Tags: state, sqflite

> Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
> databaseFactory is only initialized when using sqflite. When using `sqflite_common_ffi`
> You must call `databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;` before using global openDatabase API

I can't fix it:

> Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
> databaseFactory is only initialized when using sqflite. When using `sqflite_common_ffi`
> You must call `databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;` before using global openDatabase API